# How to functionally spread and coalesce data

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply

Just a simple little example, how might I go about renaming a column based off of a group number?

```
dat_func <- function(i){

dat %>% filter(group_no == i) %>% mutate(WHERE[i] = WHERE) %>% select(-WHERE)

}

lapply(1:max(dat$group_no), function(i) dat_func(i))
```

Taking a sample input such as this:

```
> data.frame(uniqueID= c(123,234,345,345,456),group_no=c(1,1,1,2,1), WHERE=rep("test",5))
  uniqueID group_no WHERE
1      123        1  test
2      234        1  test
3      345        1  test
4      345        2  test
5      456        1  test
```

And producing this:

```
> data.frame(uniqueID=c(123,234,345,456),WHERE1=rep("test",4), WHERE2=c(NA,NA,"test",NA))
  uniqueID WHERE1 WHERE2
1      123  test   <NA>
2      234  test   <NA>
3      345  test   test
4      456  test   <NA>
```

FINAL SOLUTION:

My original problem was a little more complicated but here's the solution I came up with:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
```

Had some duplicate data that needed to be coalesced along with repeating group assignment.

```
dat <- data.frame(uniqueID= c(123,234,345,456,456),
           TEST1=c(1,1,1,NA,1),
           TEST2=c(1,1,1,1,NA),
           WHERE=rep("test",5))
```

Generate the repeating group value.

```
dat %<>% mutate(DUPE = as.numeric(duplicated(uniqueID))+1)
```

Function to create the repeating group variables:

```
rep_group <- function(i) {

  dat %>%
    mutate(DUPE = paste0(i, DUPE)) %>%
    spread(key = DUPE, value = i)

}
```

Function to coalesce the repeating values and NAs.

```
coalesce_by_column <- function(df) {
  return(dplyr::coalesce(!!! as.list(df)))
}
```

List of repeating group variables

```
rep_list <- c("WHERE")
```

Applying the repeating group function and coalescing everything:

```
lapply(rep_list, function(i) rep_group(i)) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  select(-matches("[.]")) %>% 
  group_by(uniqueID) %>% 
  summarise_all(coalesce_by_column)
```

To summarize:

These steps take data that looks like this:

```
  uniqueID TEST1 TEST2 WHERE 
1      123     1     1  test    
2      234     1     1  test    
3      345     1     1  test    
4      456    NA     1  test    
5      456     1    NA  test
```

And generates data like this:

```
  uniqueID TEST1 TEST2 WHERE1 WHERE2
     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>  <fct> 
1      123     1     1 test   NA    
2      234     1     1 test   NA    
3      345     1     1 test   NA    
4      456     1     1 test   test
```

Comment: Added some sample code, but probably need to play around some more before I can ask it clearer.

Comment: You may need to remove the `[]` in `filter` and use `mutate(paste0(WHERE, i) :=`

Comment: After the `filter` step, why some elements are NA in 'WHERE2'.  Not clear about the condition here

Comment: Sorry it's unclear, bit of a complicated data step. I'm grouping by a repeated value and reassigning the unique values within the group to a repeating group variable. So group_no == 1 are the first group and need to be assigned to repeating group variable WHERE1, group_no == 2 need to be assigned to WHERE2 but a group_no == 2 will then be binded to the repeated group value.

Comment: In short, a group_no == 2 is a duplicate group value of the group_no == 1 preceding it. mutate(group_no = as.numeric(duplicated(uniqueID))+1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you want `group_no` to go from long to wide format. There are several ways to do this in R. Here's a solution using tidyverse (more specifically, `tidyr::spread`).

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(uniqueID= c(123,234,345,345,456),group_no=c(1,1,1,2,1), WHERE=rep("test",5))

# Long to wide
df1 <- df1 %>%
  spread(key = group_no, value = WHERE)

# Renaming columns
names(df1)[-1] <- paste0("WHERE", names(df1)[-1])
df1

  uniqueID WHERE1 WHERE2
1      123   test   <NA>
2      234   test   <NA>
3      345   test   test
4      456   test   <NA>
```

Or, you add the "column name" to `group_no` ahead of time with something like this:

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(group_no = paste0("WHERE", group_no)) %>%
  spread(key = group_no, value = WHERE)

  uniqueID WHERE1 WHERE2
1      123   test   <NA>
2      234   test   <NA>
3      345   test   test
4      456   test   <NA>
```

Comment: Now I just need to put it into a function to code the 50+ variables I need to do this to. Just an FYI, spread() is now soft-deprecated: https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/blob/master/R/pivot-wide.R